# Using spring beans in jasper reports

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have a spring bean:

```
<bean 
    id="my.package.CustomerWrapper" 
    class="my.package.CustomerWrapper">

    <property name="customerWrapperCache" ref="customerWrapperCache"></property>
</bean>
```

And in a jrxml:

```
<variable name="a_Info" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[my.package.CustomerWrapper.lookupWithMainAddress($P{cust_id}, "informationLine")]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

But this is throwing a NullPointerException because customerWrapperCache is null.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JasperReports is not using the `CustomerWrapper` bean that is managed by Spring, it is creating a new instance, which is why the `customerWrapperCache` is null;

To use a Spring bean inside a Jasper report, you need to pass the bean as a parameter to the report. See the [Jasper Reports - Populating Model and View](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jasper-reports-model) on the Spring Reference site.